# Slider not "sliding" & prev/next buttons issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

The slider/carousel I'm trying to implent is this: http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/

This is my HTML, CSS & Javascript.

Problems:

1. Images do not scroll by themselves (the button's that exist don't work either, justa   link that says "prev & "next", that I don't even want there. `I want custom .png's that should be clickable..`
2. The images aren't "sliding".
3. If you look in the .css file, you'll
   see `I tried to add buttons for next & prev, which failed.` Not sure what to put as `.hero-something-next thingy,` I saw a piece of code that I could implent by myself, but it says .slideshow-next in that one, and I know I have to have something different (name-wise), I just don't know what it should say instead.
4. There's also a line in the beginning of the .js file that keeps putting
   "Prev" & "Next" links in the slide, which I don't want. I just want
   the arrows to be the ones switching images.
5. I'm not sure what that "easing" part is, nor the "pie" thingy, and why I have it in my css, if it's even
   necessary.. (Had webdesign class for like a month, don't have that much experience, keep it simple!)

Link of what it currently looks like: imgur.com/e0lh9

**Fiddle** jsfiddle.net/P2YqR/2

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero">
<div class="hero-carousel">


<article>
  <img src="images/deadmau5/slide1.jpg" />

</article>

<article>
  <img src="images/deadmau5/slide2.jpg" />

</article>

<article>
  <img src="images/deadmau5/slide3.jpg" />

</article>
<article>

  <img src="images/deadmau5/slide4.jpg" />

</article>

</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hero-carousel').heroCarousel({
            easing: 'easeOutExpo',
            css3pieFix: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
width: 1366px;
 height: 340px; position:absolute;top:270px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 48px;margin: 0 auto; border-top:9px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, .30);border-bottom: 9px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, .30); padding: 0 0 12px 0; }

.hero-carousel article {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 470px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    }

.hero-carousel-container article {
    float: left;
    }

    .hero-carousel article img{
    border-style:solid;border-width:6px;color:#000; position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        }

    .hero-carousel article .contents {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 72px;
        left: 48px;
        list-style: none;
        color: #000;
        width: 556px;
        padding: 20px;

        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        -pie-background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);

        -moz-border-radius: 20px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;

        behavior: url(/assets/PIE.htc);
        }

    .hero-carousel-nav {
        width: 980px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -490px;
        z-index: 2;
        }



        .hero-carousel-nav li {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 48px;
            right: 48px;
            list-style: none;
}


a.hero-carousel_next{ WHAT HERE? <----
background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-right.png') no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
width: 59px;        /*width of your img*/
height: 59px;      /*height of your img*/
font-size: 0px;    /*this is better than 1px*/
}


.hero-carousel-nav_prev{ SAME HERE <---?
 background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-left.png') no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
width: 59px;        /*width of your img*/
height: 59px;      /*height of your img*/
font-size: 0px;    /*this is better than 1px*/
}
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery.fn.heroCarousel = function (a) {
    a = jQuery.extend({
        animationSpeed: 1000,
        navigation: true,
        easing: "",
        timeout: 5000,
        pause: true,
        pauseOnNavHover: true,
        prevText: "Previous",
        nextText: "Next",
        css3pieFix: false,
        currentClass: "current",
        onLoad: function () {},
        onStart: function () {},
        onComplete: function () {}
    }, a);
    if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) < 7) {
        a.animationSpeed = 0
    }
    return this.each(function () {
        var k = jQuery(this),
            b = k.children();
        currentItem = 1;
        childWidth = b.width();
        childHeight = b.height();
        if (b.length > 2) {
            b.each(function (m) {
                if (a.itemClass) {
                    jQuery(this).addClass(a.itemClass)
                }
            });
            b.filter(":first").addClass(a.currentClass).before(b.filter(":last"));
            var d = Math.round(childWidth * k.children().length),
                l = "-" + Math.round(childWidth + Math.round(childWidth / 2)) + "px";
            k.addClass("hero-carousel-container").css({
                position: "relative",
                overflow: "hidden",
                left: "50%",
                top: 0,
                "margin-left": l,
                height: childHeight,
                width: d
            });
            k.before('<ul class="hero-carousel-nav"><li class="prev"><a href="#">' + a.prevText + '</a></li><li class="next"><a href="#">' + a.nextText + "</a></li></ul>");
            var e = k.prev(".hero-carousel-nav"),
                h;
            if (a.timeout > 0) {
                var j = false;
                if (a.pause) {
                    k.hover(function () {
                        j = true
                    }, function () {
                        j = false
                    })
                }
                if (a.pauseOnNavHover) {
                    e.hover(function () {
                        j = true
                    }, function () {
                        j = false
                    })
                }
                function c() {
                    if (!j) {
                        e.find(".next a").trigger("click")
                    }
                }
                h = window.setInterval(c, a.timeout)
            }
            e.find("a").data("disabled", false).click(function (p) {
                p.preventDefault();
                var m = jQuery(this),
                    n = m.parent().hasClass("prev"),
                    o = k.children();
                if (m.data("disabled") === false) {
                    a.onStart(k, e, o.eq(currentItem), a);
                    if (n) {
                        f(o.filter(":last"), "previous")
                    } else {
                        f(o.filter(":first"), "next")
                    }
                    m.data("disabled", true);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        m.data("disabled", false)
                    }, a.animationSpeed + 200);
                    if (a.timeout > 0) {
                        window.clearInterval(h);
                        h = window.setInterval(c, a.timeout)
                    }
                }
            });

            function f(m, q) {
                var o = parseFloat(k.position().left),
                    n = parseFloat(k.css("margin-left"));
                if (q === "previous") {
                    m.before(m.clone().addClass("carousel-clone"));
                    k.prepend(m);
                    var p = Math.round(n - childWidth);
                    var r = "+="
                } else {
                    m.after(m.clone().addClass("carousel-clone"));
                    k.append(m);
                    var p = l;
                    var r = "-="
                }
                if (a.css3pieFix) {
                    g(jQuery(".carousel-clone"))
                }
                k.css({
                    left: o,
                    width: Math.round(d + childWidth),
                    "margin-left": p
                }).animate({
                    left: r + childWidth
                }, a.animationSpeed, a.easing, function () {
                    k.css({
                        left: "50%",
                        width: d,
                        "margin-left": n
                    });
                    jQuery(".carousel-clone").remove();
                    i()
                })
            }
            function g(n) {
                var m = n.attr("_pieId");
                if (m) {
                    n.attr("_pieId", m + "_cloned")
                }
                n.find("*[_pieId]").each(function (o, p) {
                    var q = $(p).attr("_pieId");
                    $(p).attr("_pieId", q + "_cloned")
                })
            }
            function i() {
                var m = k.children();
                m.removeClass(a.currentClass).eq(currentItem).addClass(a.currentClass);
                a.onComplete(k, k.prev(".hero-carousel-nav"), m.eq(currentItem), a)
            }
            if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
                e.find("a").attr("hideFocus", "true")
            }
            a.onLoad(k, e, k.children().eq(currentItem), a)
        }
    })
};
```

And please, when providing answers, hold like a few minutes 'til I respond with confirmation that it works!

Result should be similar to that of: http://www.deadmau5.com

**UPDATE**

```
.hero-carousel-nav li.next a { 
background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-right.png') no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;        /*width of your img*/
height: 120px;      /*height of your img*/
font-size: 0px; 
right: -15px;  /*this is better than 1px*/
bottom: 90px;
}


.hero-carousel-nav li.prev a { 
 background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-left.png') no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;        /*width of your img*/
height: 120px;      /*height of your img*/
font-size: 0px;    /*this is better than 1px*/
left: -50px;
bottom: 90px;               
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
   .hero-carousel-nav {
    width: 980px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -490px;
    z-index: 2;
    }



    .hero-carousel-nav li {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 48px;
        right: 48px;
        list-style: none;
}
.hero-carousel-nav li.prev {
left: -50px;
right: auto;
bottom: 100px;
}
.hero-carousel-nav li.next {
right: -30px;
left: auto;
bottom: 100px;
}
.hero-carousel-nav li a {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D21034;

 color: #FFFFFF;
 display: block;
 float: left;


}

.hero-carousel-nav li.next a { 
background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-right.png') no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
width: 115px;        /*width of your img*/
height: 100px;      /*height of your img*/
font-size: 0px; 
right: -15px;  /*this is better than 1px*/
bottom: 100px;
overflow:hidden;

}


.hero-carousel-nav li.prev a { 
background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-left.png') no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
width: 115px;        /*width of your img*/
height: 100px;      /*height of your img*/
font-size: 0px;    /*this is better than 1px*/
left: -50px;
bottom: 100px;
overflow:hidden;

}
```

Comment: Easing refers to the motion pattern of each slide, e.g. linear easing means that the slide will move at a constant speed. PIE is an acronym for Progressive Internet Explorer, and it's a polyfill meant to add CSS3 functionality to IE

Comment: check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/au7jh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly updated your fiddle. See full result here http://jsfiddle.net/johnsmith123/P2YqR/11/

First added jsfiddle and easyng lib (see in resources section on fiddle)
then moved

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hero-carousel').heroCarousel({
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        css3pieFix: true
    });
});
```

to script setion.

Update

Images: http://jsfiddle.net/johnsmith123/P2YqR/11/

CSS:

```
.hero-carousel-nav li.prev {
    left: 48px;
    right: auto;
}

.hero-carousel-nav li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D21034;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}


.hero-carousel-nav li.next a{
background: url('http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/themes/deadmau5/css/../images/large-arrow-right.png') no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
width: 59px;        /*width of your img*/
height: 89px;      /*height of your img*/
font-size: 0px;    /*this is better than 1px*/
  }


.hero-carousel-nav li.prev a{
    background: url('http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/themes/deadmau5/css/../images/large-arrow-left.png')    no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 59px;        /*width of your img*/
    height: 89px;      /*height of your img*/
    font-size: 0px;    /*this is better than 1px*/
}
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work? I switched out the .css with my existing one, what else do I have to do? Should I also grab the resources you put and replace mine with them? Also the "Next" & "Prev" are still there. I know it's determined right at the start of the .js, but I don't wanna change too much as I'm not experienced and screw this whole thing over.. I basically want them gone & be able to put my own .png's that should be clickable (arrows) instead.

Comment: Basically as of now, I can click the prev & next buttons, only one of them at a certain point, which eventually leads to 3 of the same pics showing... also they're not sliding..

Comment: When adding the easing.js, it starts to slide. The Prev & Next links work, however I want .png's instead. Thing is, it slides to a pic, and when it's about to stop, it switches to a different pic than what is supposed to be showing? Basically, I have 4 images. If number 1 is showing, it slides to picture number 2, and right when it's about to stop, it switches to pic number 3 (no sliding). EDIT: The latter issue is fixed, somehow, it just stopped. NOW I just want to replace the existing "Prev" & "Next" that are being controlled in the .js with .pngs from the .css file.. Help?

Comment: Adding `.hero-carousel-nav li.prev { left: 48px; right: auto; }` fixed it, they are now positioned (not as I want it but that I can fix myself!), and are clickable. Thank you, you deserve all the thanks in the world!

Answer (score 1):

```
.hero-carousel-nav {
  width: 980px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -490px;
  z-index: 2;
}



.hero-carousel-nav li {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 48px;
    right: 48px;
    list-style: none;
}

.hero-carousel-nav li a {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D21034;

   color: #FFFFFF;
   display: block;
   float: left;
 }

.hero-carousel-nav li.next a { 
    background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-right.png') no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 82px;        /*width of your img*/
    height: 82px;      /*height of your img*/
    font-size: 0px; 
    right: -15px;  /*this is better than 1px*/
    bottom: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }


.hero-carousel-nav li.prev a { 
   background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-left.png') no-repeat;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 82px;        /*width of your img*/
   height: 82px;      /*height of your img*/
   font-size: 0px;    /*this is better than 1px*/
   left: -50px;
   bottom: 100px;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: How come yours are actually clickable and mine are not? I managed to get my .png's inside, but they're not clickable. Check question again, updated at bottom with new code. Never mind, I saw you had `li.next a`, I forgot the `a`. This made them clickable, but they appear in the same position. Updating question now. Mainly because, before I added the .pngs, the "Prev" & "Next" links would be on the same spot as well. I do believe I may have removed some code in the .css when trying to get rid of them, before realizing that they were controlled in the .js

Comment: Only thing now is, there's an area that's still clickable around a tiny bit outside of the `.png's`, I updated the question if you wanna look into that, otherwise I'll just leave it like this. It's only a school-project! I can't upvote, my rep has to be 15 and it's only 6..

Comment: okay no-issues. Sorry i just seen that you have selected your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Example can be seen here, on the right (-->) arrow: http://imgur.com/4oKqe If it's an easy fix and you don't mind, otherwise I'm still so thankful to you!

Comment: see the updated css codes actually your li.next a has a width morethan  the image size. so i reduced it, Plz see if this works for you.

Comment: Well, what it does is that, it creates a clickable box the same size as the `.png`, but the image gets cropped.. You'll see here: http://imgur.com/klL6a It's clickable outside of the `.png` to the left & top. jsFiddle of the .css only : http://jsfiddle.net/SCVQL/

Comment: this is the image url:http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/themes/deadmau5/images/large-arrow-right.png

Comment: this img has space shadow outside that's why clickable.

Comment: So.. I want the shadow to be there as well. How large should the image be then? EDIT: I set it to 110, 110, just seems that the area's clickable to the left & top even outside of the shadow.

Comment: plz calulate i have uploaded the img with red border up plz look. you need to crop img as per your need.

Comment: Well, I did set it to 110x110, but no matter what settings, the clickable area is still larger to the left & top. There's always like an extra 10px to the left & top somehow?

Comment: need to position the background image like this **background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-right.png') -10px -10px no-repeat;*-* see the negative positions for left top

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! Haha, however.. When I click the `.png` and move away the mouse, that box'd, dotted area appears. This is the last thing I'll ask!

Comment: just add **outline:none;**

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this, taking your time and all.. I've got 11 rep so soon as I reach 15 I'll up your answers! Once again thank you!!

Comment: not an issue with the upvote i am glad that i helped you. plz carry on with your project. if you really want to upvote then upvote the selected answer. That helped you getting out of it. Good Luck and Develop more... Thanks! I must say thats '**Bad Habit**'.

Comment: Haha! I am, made my logo & a border underneath in in .css with a div only in html rather than the whole img src in html etcetc. Thank you, once again! Right now: http://imgur.com/dtVpR Thanks!